# Get selected image to Controller Class with enctype="multipart/form-data"?

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, file-upload, multipartform-data

**JSP:**

```
<form action="addUpdateSchool" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <table align="center">
            <tr>
                <td>School Name :</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="school_name" name="school_name" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Address :</td>
                <td><textarea rows="4" cols="30" id="address" name="address"></textarea> </td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
                <td>Logo :</td>
                <td><input type="file" id="logo" name="logo"/></td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" onclick="return validation();" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
```

I'm trying to get all above form properties at the **Controller** class including logo, but its showing null.

How can i resolve it?

**Controller Class:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addSchool", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addSchool(@ModelAttribute SchoolModel schoolModel, HttpSession session) {

     System.out.println("name: "+schoolModel.getSchool_name);

}
```

Comment: The code has apparently no errors.Can you give more details. Besides 'schoolModel.getSchool_name' should be a method. Is that a typo error?

Comment: @vineethsivan: Im getting the name, if i remove enctype="multipart/form-data"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="10000000" /> <!-- setting maximum upload size -->
</bean>
```

**Controller Class:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addUpdateSchool", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addSchool(@RequestParam("logo") MultipartFile multipartFile, @ModelAttribute SchoolModel schoolModel) {
    String path="";
    try{
        MultipartFile file = multipartFile;
        if(file.getOriginalFilename().trim().length()>0) {
            path=saveFile(file, multipartFile.getOriginalFilename());
        }else{
            path="";
        }
        System.out.println("path: "+path);
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static String saveFile(MultipartFile file, String name) throws IOException{
    byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
    Random random = new Random();       
    File dir = new File("D:\WebSLCMImages\WebSLCM\"); // Path to Save Image
    if (!dir.exists()){
        dir.mkdirs();
    }
    String path = dir+"/" + getFileName(name) + System.currentTimeMillis() + Math.abs(random.nextInt())+ getFileExtension(name);
    File serverFile = new File(path);
    BufferedOutputStream stream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(serverFile));
    stream.write(bytes);
    stream.close();
    return path;
}
```

**Note: Don't forget to add related jar files (commons-fileupload-1.3.jar)**

**Reference link:** [MVC-Multipart-Resolver](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/mvc.html#mvc-multipart-resolver)

Answer (score 1):

You have to add `multipartResolver` in your application context in order to handle `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in the view page.
Add the following in your application contex xml file

```
<bean id="multipartResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver" />
```

and add the appropriate jar file in your class path.

For more information you can see the documentation in spring [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/mvc.html#mvc-multipart-resolver)